# How to insert data with On Conflict it will replace in sqlite

Tags: node-sqlite3

I have facing an issue while running sql query for bulk Insert and while inserting it was throwing an error that ***SQLITE_ERROR: near "ON": syntax error***

I am using sqlite3: 3.22.0 version

and my DLL file was look like

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id               INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
    sessionId        INTEGER     REFERENCES sessions (sessionid),
    name             String
    UNIQUE (
        sessionId,
        name
    )
    ON CONFLICT REPLACE
);
```

Inserting bulk data on single query through sequelize.

My code is ..

```
db.myTable.bulkCreate(tableData).then(function(data) { 
     if(data){
        res.json({success: true});
     }
}, function(err) {  
      res.json({ success: false, msg: "Error while importing session"});
})
```

Here on above code the **tableData** have the array of data to be inserted.

while running this bulk insert it was showing ***SQLITE_ERROR: near "ON": syntax error*** error!!